# Size Does Matter (at least referring to bottles)

Tags: code-golf, number

## Introduction

I have an **even** number of bottles, all of different sizes. Unfortunately, I only know the size of the smallest bottle: **300ml**.

I also know the following:

- Half of the bottles are twice the size of the other half, meaning that the smallest small bottle and the smallest large bottle are in a ratio of 2:1.
- The smaller bottles, from smallest to largest, increase in size by n%, where n is the number of bottles multiplied by 3.

Could you help find what sizes my bottles are?

## Challenge

Your input is to be an **even** number of bottles.

The output should be the size of all of the small bottles (from smallest to largest), then all of the large bottles (from smallest to largest).

## Example I/O

In: `2` 
Out: `300, 600`

In: `4` 
Out: `300, 336, 600, 672`

In: `10` 
Out: `300, 390, 507, 659.1, 856.83, 600, 780, 1014, 1318.2, 1713.66`

(Note: commas are unnecessary; this answer can be formatted in any way you want as long as all of the "small" bottles come before the "large" bottles.)

## Rules

Standard [loophole rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/1789#1789) apply.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

## Winners

**Esoteric Languages**
15 bytes 
[05AB1E by Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195748/89826)

**Standard Languages**
36 bytes 
[Mathematica by attinat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195781/89826)

Comment: In the third testcase, does it mean 856.83 is smaller one but 600 is larger one? It is confusing.

Comment: Yes - the size of "smaller" bottles can be larger than the "larger" bottles.

Comment: Essentially, the first half of your output should be the "smaller" bottles, and the second half should be the "larger" bottles.

Comment: Doesn't **"(at least referring to bottles)"** make the title even worse when you think about it?

Comment: Let's not go there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₆v;F.03*>NmyтP,
```

Port of [*@TFeld*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195739/52210), so make sure to upvote him.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVNbmbWbnoGxlp1fbuXFpgCd//8NDQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX3lopQ6Xkn9pCYSv8/9RU1vZoXXWbofW6RkYa9n55VZebArQ@V9be2ib/f9oIx0THUODWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
₆                # Push builtin integer 36
 v               # Loop `y` over both digits:
  ;              #  Halve the (implicit) input-integer
   F             #  Inner loop `N` in the range [0, input/2):
    .03*         #   Multiply the (implicit) input by 0.03
                 #   (alternative 4-byter: `т/3*` # divide by 100, multiply by 3)
        >        #   Increase this by 1
         Nm      #   Take it to the power `N`
           yт    #   Push both `y` and 100
             P   #   And take the product of the entire stack
              ,  #   Then pop and print this number with trailing newline
```

Comment: *Wait*, 05AB1E has floating-point literals‽ I always assumed this wouldn't work, since `.` is used for extended commands.

Comment: Here's [another 15](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fz8BYy87T2scm99jWwx1aFYdW//9vaAAA), [another 15](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@tjWwx3ndh9arGdg7Kllp1VbcWj1//@GBgA), and [yet another one](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9vc2FiaWX//zs8w4UzKtGCLz7GtcOIxaHOt1B4wqv//zEw).
There are lots of possible approaches, but I'm not finding anything shorter.

Comment: @Grimmy The new version of 05AB1E indeed had floating point literals :) In the legacy version this wasn't available yet, but it's something new _Adnan_ added in the rewrite.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```python
lambda n:[a*(1+.03*n)**i*75for a in 4,8for i in range(n/2)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpRS8NQW8/AWCtPU0srU8vcNC2/SCFRITNPwUTHAsTOBLGLEvPSUzXy9I00Y/8XFGXmlSikaRhpcsGYJgimoYHmfwA)

<sub>-1 byte, thanks to Joseph Sible</sub>

Comment: It confuses me that you've managed to get `[300.0, 336.00000000000006, 600.0, 672.0000000000001]`. Where did the extra 0's come from?

Comment: That's [floating point precision](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for you..

Comment: @Corsaka That's caused by the same thing that makes many languages say `0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3` is true

Comment: -1 byte: use 75, 4, and 8 in place of 100, 3, and 6.

Comment: @JosephSible Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 36 bytes

```
{#,2#}&[300(1+.03#)^Range[0,#/2-1]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7v1pZx0i5Vi3a2MBAw1Bbz8BYWTMuKDEvPTXaQEdZ30jXMDZW7X9AUWZeSbSyrl2ag3Ksmr5DNZeRDpeJDpehAVftfwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
×.03‘*HḶ$×300;Ḥ$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//w5cuMDPigJgqSOG4tiTDlzMwMDvhuKQk////MTA)

-2 bytes thanks to Nick Kennedy

## Explanation

```
×.03‘*HḶ$×300;Ḥ$  Main Link
×.03              Multiply the number of bottles by 3%
    ‘             Increment (add 100%)
     *            (Vectorized) exponent to the power of:
      HḶ$         [0, 1, ..., n-1]
         ×300     Multiply each factor by 300
             ;Ḥ$  Double the list and append it
```

Comment: `×.03` saves two bytes.

Comment: @NickKennedy Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <strike>42</strike> 38 bytes

```julia
f(n,z=[75*(1+.03n).^(0:n÷2-1)])=4z,8z
```

-4 bytes using ideas from John and Joseph Sible.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00jT6fKNtrcVEvDUFvPwDhPUy9Ow8Aq7/B2I11DzVhNW5MqHYuq/w7FGfnlCmkaRppcMKYJgmlooPkfAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 47 bytes

```hs
f n=[75*a*(1+0.03*n)**i|a<-[4,8],i<-[0..n/2-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYixDoIwAAV3vuKFOEAptSBGY8TJOLk5YmNqgNBYWgI1Lv57BZd7966T06vR2qt@sKPDWTrJLlbX8qkbRK0dH3EQ9FIZlFgeqpwWNOMCK9wN0hNqGwDD293ceDVznTr7gUGSIDwgXPZfohYm9jPKarclkkRZwhnfEBMTor7ymFYF3QuqZuGMmXWeZkJ4/wM)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
n=input()/2
for c in 4,8:exec"print c*75;c*=1+.06*n;"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvLCsMgEEX3@Yoh3SRGrKPxkQb/pDuJNJuJBAvt11tLuzmHy@Hmd3kcpGoK90php/wsw3hVXTpOiLATzNzfttcW@3zuVCAyZ9bIAk5CWkZrz6j@Shr@77G7aCk56KXBSMfBmkUgB2@s8LrNb3W@ASXOjRq9UM0OtbC2ovwA)

The `*75` trick is taken from other answers.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 63 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,b=300,r=1+n*9/b,h=n/2)=>n?[b,...f(n-1,--h?b*r:600,r,h)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBCoMwEADAe1@S1U1MbClUWH2IeDBqmhbZSBS/H/EoXof593u/DvG3bJLDOKXkSDBaemqNkUzO2aew6ImLEqjmprWolHKCpUEpfWOzWL3Pix66qu3SEHgN86Tm8BVOlACPq7xuYjRAOgA)

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZcjBDoIwDADQu1/S4loKGA8khQ8hHBjC0JDODMPvz7PxHd9rOqdjTs/3hyw@lrxqNu0gqNfOiPrBO2YOQLT1vkjtXQTHdhgRGhGXtLpawdK4Ta2sMc/RjrgvvMcAK9SIl9@5/U0liPkL)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjT6fC1tjAQCfbNk/T1i5PV9c@ukJHT08vDSiTrZunm2dfoa1nYKyVrVVhZQZSpxlrFR37Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI03DSFOTC1XEBEPE0EBT8z8A)

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZchBCoNADADAe1@SWBPSKj0I0YeIB7G61JWsqMj@fnsW5zhzf/b7sP3Wgyx8xzRpMq3BadTaiJo25szswJORNfHJUmQ@i9VHBLuq7RAKkdyrYRqC7WEZeQkOJngjPq5T3uYliOkP), expanding on @Arnauld's improvements.

Comment: @Arnauld Maybe you could post as another answer. It is different enough as another answer, imo.

Comment: @Arnauld And use the idea from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195738/size-does-matter-at-least-referring-to-bottles/195740?noredirect=1#comment465848_195739), it is [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZchLCoMwEADQvSeZSZ1Bq8UijB5EXIifYCOTUovk9nEtvuX7DMewj7/1@yf10xwXiSoNWAnSKFHbBVO9Uma24EhJ2/DgrDDOhPqNfd31CGXqRDGOXne/zbx5Cws8EZPrlLfJM8R4Ag)

Comment: Congrats on the gold [tag:code-golf] badge!

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>70</s> 62 bytes

```php
for($s=300;$i++<$n=$argn;$s=$n/2-$i?$s+$s*$n*.03:600)echo$s,_;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFSKbY0NDKxVMrW1bVTybFUSi9LzrIGCKnn6RroqmfYqxdoqxVoqeVp6BsZWZgYGmqnJGfkqxTrx1v9BLAWlmDwla67SvOLUEg2VTE04M0vT@r8RlwmXocG//IKSzPy84v@6bgA)

Output numbers are seperated by `_`.

Alternative for `$s+$s*$n*.03` can be `$s*=1+$n*.03` too, but both are same length.

Comment: I'm getting errors with this one. Seems to be complaining that `i` was never defined

Comment: @Corsaka those are warnings or notices in `stderr` and are totally fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```
procedure f(n)
write(!36*(1+.03*n)^(0to n/2-1)*100)&\z
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0zOz/v/v6AoPzk1pbQoVSFNI0@Tq7wosyRVQ9HYTEvDUFvPwFgrTzNOw6AkXyFP30jXUFPL0MBAUy2miis1LwVJa25iZp6GJpcCEKSWpRZVKuRZ2RrVmNQYGiik5CtUg422VoCYralQC9YNAA)

Saved 2 bytes by replacing `(3|6)`(alternate 3 with 6) with `!36`. `!`generates the components of a data object. When applied to a number it generates its digits. In [`Unicon`](http://unicon.org/) - the descendent of `Icon` - `!n` generates the numbers in the range 1..n.

Comment: What's the point of `\z`? TIO doesn't understand it.

Comment: @Corsaka `3|6` and `0to n/2-1` are generators and normally I would write `every write((3|6)*...)`. Icon have a bactracking mechanism though and when an expression fails, it backtracks to fetch another value from the preceding generator(s). `\z` checks if the value `z` is non-null and since `z` is not present (declared), it backtracks until the 2 generators are exhausted.

Comment: @Corsaka TIO only complains that I use a variable that is not declared. [Here](https://tio.run/##TY1BCsIwEEX3OcWsZCZSTVpxoXgTEUoyQqDOSKgVNZ69Stz4Vn/z/ktBZZ6vWQPHW2Y4o5C55zQyYle2ZNEvV66zQid0o4Ks28aT9c7R4vg0LPFPvvRJkAx8GTT0A0jdPHF@gOwObdkU7yAqvGpoD78Swbs@fQA) I declared the variable `n` in the main procedure and it stopped compaining about `n`, only `z` remained.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>57</s> 53 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.times.map{|a|300*(1+a*2/n)*(1+0.03*n)**a%=n/2}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@vJDM3tVgvN7GguiaxxtjAQEvDUDtRy0g/TxPEMtAzMNYCMrUSVW3z9I1qa/8XKKRFG8VygSgTCGVoEPsfAA)

Comment: -1 byte: use 75, 4, and 8 in place of 100, 3, and 6.

Comment: Thanks, but I've found a better way.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>66</s> 54 bytes

<sup>-12 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
param($n)300,600|%{$y=$_;1..($n/2)|%{$y;$y*=1+$n*.03}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT9PYwEDHzMCgRrVapdJWJd7aUE8PKKxvpAkWsVap1LI11FbJ09IzMK6t/c9Vy8WlppKmYMSlrg5mmMAYZjCGocF/AA)

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT1Ol0tbYwMDaUE8PyNM30qxRrVaptFap1DICEbaG2ip5WnoGxrU1xflFJf@5arm41FTSFIy41NXBDBMYwwzGMDT4DwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy breaks on the last test case. The last Small Bottle (856.83) is larger than the first Big Bottle (600)

Comment: oO! thanks. Very strange comment "the size of "smaller" bottles can be larger than the "larger" bottles". Ok. Another [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b8gsSgxV0MlT9PYwEDHzMCgRrVapdJWJd7aUE8PKKxvpAkWsVap1LI11FbJ09IzMK6t/c9Vy8WlppKmYMSlrg5mmMAYZjCGocF/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 32 bytes

```
{s,2*s:(-1+x%2)((1+.03*x)*)\300}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82quljHSKvYSkPXULtC1UhTQ8NQW8/AWKtCU0szxtjAoPZ/moKhwX8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
ＮθＦ²Ｅ⊘θＩ××³⁰⁰⊕ιＸ⊕×θ·⁰³κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05orLb9IQcNIUyGgKDOvRMM3sUDDIzGnLDUFKKmj4JxYXKIRkpmbWgwljQ0MdBQ885KLUnNT80qAqjI1gcoC8suBpiELQ1QX6ijoGRiDVGRrAoH1//@GBv91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs each list element on a separate line. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`

```
Ｆ²
```

Loop `i` twice, once for the small sizes, once for the large sizes.

```
Ｅ⊘θ
```

Loop `k` over half of the number of bottles, and implicitly output each calculation on its own line.

```
Ｉ××³⁰⁰⊕ιＸ⊕×θ·⁰³κ
```

Calculate `300(i+1)(.03n+1)ᵏ` and cast the result to string.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 46 bytes

```
x=scan();b=300*(1+0.03*x)^(0:(x/2-1));c(b,b*2)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTOsnW2MBAS8NQ20DPwFirQjNOw8BKo0LfSNdQU9M6WSNJJ0nLSPO/ocF/AA)

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet tldr, make a function that accepts x.

Comment: @gggg bummer. Reversed back to the standard scan-based approach, then

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 84 bytes

```forth
: x dup 2/ 0 do fdup f. fover f* loop ; : f dup s>f .03e f* 1e f+ 3e2 x 6e2 fnip x ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoQwFEP3niJrRa06zELBy9hGBfGXzijevv7qJi8hIZTwX8qZCTH2uGAPj7aGgRUwBVagnC6AOTYRjwE9@Ox@I1GZzqWqUS3QuVY/vqrcV692iGoxhezzojEP4w0)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
\ helper function to extract out common logic from the small and large numbers
: x               \ start a new word definition
  dup 2/          \ duplicate the input and divide by 2
  0 do            \ loop from 0 to n/2
    fdup f.       \ print the top of the floating point stack
    fover f*      \ multiple the top float stack value by the 2nd float stack value
  loop            \ end the loop
;

: f               \ start a new word definition
  dup s>f         \ duplicate n and place a copy on the float stack
  0.03e f*        \ multiple by 0.03 (multiply by 3 and divide by 100)
  1e f+           \ add 1 to get our increase multiplier
  3e2 x           \ print the smaller numbers by starting with 300
  6e2 fnip x      \ drop the remaining small number and print the large numbers from 600
;                 \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 23 bytes

```
Fk2Fb/Q2*300*hk^h*.03Qb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3y3byC1JP9BIy9jAQCsjOy5DS8/AODDp/38zAA)

Port of [@TFeld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195739/90146)'s answer, which I was able to make decently concise. Cant help but feel like there's a more clever answer with Pyth but I wasnt able to find it.

### How it Works

```
Fk2Fb/Q2*300*hk^h*.03Qb
Fk2                     - For k in range(2)
   Fb/Q2                - For b in range(input/2)
        *300*hk         - 300 times k+1 times...
                h*.03Q  - 1 + 0.03 times input
               ^      b - The above to the exponent b
                          Implicitly prints the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

Two independent 40-byte answers: the first is an unnamed function, the second is a named function `g`, both taking one argument.

```
Table[300i(1+.03#)^j,{i,2},{j,0,#/2-1}]&

g@n_:=300#(1+.03n)^(#2-1)&~Array~{2,n/2}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 89 bytes

```java
n->{for(int k=0,i;++k<3;)for(i=0;i<n/2;)System.out.println(Math.pow(.03*n+1,i++)*k*300);}
```

Port of [*@TFeld*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195739/52210), so make sure to upvote him.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY@xDoIwEIZ3n@LGlkKt4lbxDWBhNA61ghbwIFA1hvDsWJDRwaXJ/ffl/q@FeqqguJSjrlTXQawM9isAgzZrc6UzSKYR4FmbC2jickAqXTSs3NNZZY2GBBAiGDE49HndzlAZCd9Ixsp9KOkcRkKaPa63kqbvzmZ3Xj8sb1oHV0hiZW@8qV@Ei9BDtvENY9QrvVAIKodxKmwe58p1LZWzz93ZktS6G9fjCRT9qiLXZDs7AvyoWjYTtfuL2ojlw8P4AQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                              // Method with integer parameter and no return-type
  for(int k=0,i;++k<3;)           //  Loop `k` in the range (0,3) (basically [1,2]):
    for(i=0;i<n/2;)               //   Inner loop `i` in the range [0, i/2):
      System.out.println(         //    Print with trailing newline:
        Math.pow(.03*n            //     `n` multiplied by 0.03
                 +1               //     incremented by 1
                   ,i++)          //     to the power `i`
                        *k*300);} //     multiplied by `k` and 300
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>79</s> 74 <s>77</s> bytes

78 if the dash in compile arg is ignored.
Port of TField answer.
Increase in bytes is to comply with rules.

-5 bytes thanks to ceilingcat and bznein

```c
b;c;f(a){for(b=0;++b<3;c=0)while(c<a/2)printf("%f ",pow(.03*a+1,c++)*b*300);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpLCoMwEADQtZ6iCIWZRJtouhs9TDJ0bCB@sAUX4tWbFrp6m8fNyJxzICYBj4csG4TBktahd8SDxf0Z0wO496bDdYvzW6C6yqWq12WHm3XK67ZmrVEF5axFOvPk4wx4lIUxAh1SWQjc/7S/UJ75w5L8@MpNmr4)

Comment: You can also replace `for(;c<a/2;)` with `while(c<a/2)`

Comment: Is it required for the function to be able to be called multiple times?

Comment: [Yes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4939/do-function-submissions-have-to-be-reusable)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 79 bytes

```
Fn.new{|n|
for(a in[300,600])for(i in 1..n/2){
System.print(a)
a=a+a*n*0.03
}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uiavhistv0gjUSEzL9rYwEDHzMAgVhMkkgkUUTDU08vTN9Ks5gquLC5JzdUrKMrMK9FI1ORKtE3UTtTK0zLQMzDmquWq/Q8yVy85MSdHw0TzPwA)

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 81 bytes

TField answer turns out to be longer.

```
Fn.new{|n|
for(i in 0...n/2)for(a in[3,6])System.print(a*(1+0.03*n).pow(i)*100)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxDoIwEAbgnae48a6a8xDj5soLOBqHhpSkCf6QijZEfPYq6zd8OQWUt0/Uv9DRhUoLRcifFWvVj4kjRZCpKg5H2cD/4dbsz3e5Ls85PHRKETN7x/XO1BoH0WnMHMXVZlJ9yzZr54eBT1J@)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>27</s> 23 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_+3/L*Z*U}h[300]Uz
cUmÑ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=XyszL0wqWipVfWhbMzAwXVV6CmNVbdE&input=WzIsNCwxMF0KLW0KLVE)

```
_+3/L*Z*U} // function returning next element
h[300]Uz // runs the above func. U/2 times, starting from 300
cU®Ñ // concat the array obtained with the array multiplied * 2
```

Saved 4 thanks to @Shaggy

Comment: [23 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=XyszL0wqWipVfWhbMzAwXVV6CmNVbdE&input=WzIsNCwxMF0KLW0KLVE)

Comment: #Ĭ == 300 in terms of bytes! Lol

Comment: yup. But you save a byte by avoiding UTF encoding, where `Ñ` is 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 20 bytes

```
S+mDmo*300`^→*.03¹ŀ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1g71yU3X8vYwCAh7lHbJC09A@NDO482HNr7//9/QwMA) A port of the [standard answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195739).